# HTTP Error 405 when JS is in its own file, but not when in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small text censor web app im working on. Whenever the .js is in its own file and I click the 'censor text' button, I get a HTTP error 405, but if i put the js in the HTML  tag, it works fine.Not too sure why.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document Censor</title>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Text Censor</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum enim reiciendis recusandae aliquid delectus
        consectetur nobis. Sunt exercitationem iure dolores provident obcaecati aliquam totam. Molestiae cumque ducimus
        aliquid. Deserunt, provident.</p>
    <form name="redacted" method="post" action="">
        <textarea id="input" name="text" rows="10" cols="60">
        </textarea>
        <br />
        <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Censor Text" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('formSub');

function censorWords(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var textContent = document.getElementById('input');
   var redacted = ["boston", "red", "sox"];
   console.log(textContent.value)
   textContent.value = censored(textContent.value, redacted);
}

function censored(string, filters) {
   console.log('in')
   // "i" ignores case, "g" for global and "|" for OR match
   var regexp = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
   return string.replace(regexp, function (match) {
       //this is where the words are replaced with X
       var censorship = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
           censorship += 'x';
       }
       return censorship
   })
}

div.addEventListener('click', censorWords)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but my guess is you need to move your `<script src=""/>` 
to the end of the body.

Because the javascript is being loaded before the HTML itself.

```js
<body>
-
-
-
-
-
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `405` (`method not allowed`) is shown because the form is submitted and uses the `post` method but the web server doesn't allow posting to simple html files.

The submit buttons submits the form because the event listener is not correctly linked up with the `censorWords` function.

First of all, you don't need a form and you don't need a button of type submit if you only want to trigger some JavaScript to execute. Remove the form and make the button of `type=button`.

Second, before the javascript code tries to access parts of the document, you should make sure the the document is fully loaded. See [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) for several ways how to achieve that. Either wait for docment to be loaded completely and only then execute code to hook up other events. Or use the `defer` attribute on the `script` tag to defer execution of the external code until the document is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

405 error means Method Not Allowed

Your JS code isnt making any http requests, so my guess is that when you have the JS in a separate file, it is not actually being run at all, so when you press the button, it is just submitting the form

When the JS is in a separate file you still need a  element to include your JS file in your html file